# Django date filter not showing formatted timestamp in rendered template

Tags: django-templates

I'm trying to format a timestamp into a date using Django's `{{ timestamp|date:"d M Y" }}` feature.

I'm running into a problem where I can output and see the raw timestamp with `{{ timestamp }}`, but the formatting via filter isn't outputting anything when my page is rendered using `{{ timestamp|date:"d M Y" }}`.

For example, right now the result of `{{ timestamp }} - {{ timestamp|date:"d M Y" }}` is `1317945600 -` when I load the page.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that date doesnt want a timestamp, it wants a datetime or date object.
you have to parse the timestamp in python or make a templatetag.

add this to templatetags/mytags.py

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter("timestamp")
def timestamp(value):
    try:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value)
    except AttributeError:
        return ''
```

Then use it with

```
{{ some_timestamp_value|timestamp|date:"format..." }}
```